# For the partial order R = {(2,2),(4,2),(6,2),(6,3),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)} is the following answer for maximal and minimal elements correct?

Tags: relations

Maximal elements: 2,3 and 5
Minimal elements: 4,5 and 6

I just want to confirm to make sure that I understand maximal and minimal elements correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Those which appear only on the left side, are minimal, those only on the right side are maximal (after having removed the $(a,a)$ pairs, to be precise).

Comment: Thank you for confirming :)